# How do I find mongodb write statistics per database?

Tags: mongodb

How do I get write stats per database and per collection?  `mongostat` seems to only provide write info globally for the server.  Is there a way to get more granular detail about i/o?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is another similar tool, [mongotop](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongotop/) which provides statistics on per collection level.

On a Linux machine you can use iostat to provide disk level I/O statistics.

```
iostat -xmt 1
```